# Having trouble with python deepsum recursion, gives a type error?

Tags: python

So I was practicing recursion for my final exam, and was trying to make a deepsum function, which works like so:

```
deepsum([1, 2], 3, [4, 6]) => 16
```

For some reason, I keep getting this error, despite when I am tracing it seems to be correct:

in deepsum:

```
return L[0] + deepsum(L[1:])
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
```

Code:

```
def deepsum(L):

if not L:
    return 0

if L[0] == type(L):

    return deepsum(L[0])

else:
    return L[0] + deepsum(L[1:])
```

No answers with loops please; only recursion. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the way you are checking the type of `L[0]`, use [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
def deepsum(L):
    if not L:
        return 0
    if isinstance(L[0], list):
        return deepsum(L[0]) + deepsum(L[1:])
    else:
        return L[0] + deepsum(L[1:])


result = deepsum([[1, 2], 3, [4, 6]])
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
16
```

Also note that you must add the result of the remainder of the list, i.e. `deepsum(L[0]) + deepsum(L[1:])`.

Comment: @ZachZ Glad I could aid, please consider marking the answer as accepted, if you found it helpful.

Comment: Need to wait another 45 seconds :)